# Question on proof of Sylow's first theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group $p$ a prime.If $p^{k}$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $p^{k}$.

Confusing part for me in proof :

consider the class equation of the form $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum|G:C(a)|$.

where we sum over a representative of each conjugacy class $cl(a)$ where $a \notin Z(G)$.

"Since $p^{k}$ divides $|G|=|G:C(a)||C(a)|$ and $p^{k}$ does not divide $|C(a)|$, where $C(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$.''

My confusion is, why this step holds. Why cannot $p^{k}$ divide the order of the centralizer of $a$? I understand everything except the reason why $p^{k}$ cannot divide the centralizer order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be an observation earlier in the proof (maybe at the very beginning) that, if $p^k$ divides the order of a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, then we're done by induction on $|G|$, because a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ would also be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

After this observation, we can assume that $p^k$ doesn't divide the order of any proper subgroup of $G$. That includes the centralizers $C(a)$ for all $a\notin Z(G)$.